# Reset and repeat setinterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I have a function for run the setInterval(). I wanna

1. start setInterval
2. reset setInterval
3. start setInterval

+1, +2, +3 subscription and then but not resetting, adding but not clearing.

```
    if(eventData.type=="subscription"){
    //code to handle subscription events
    console.log(eventData)
    abone_sayisi++

    if (geri_say!=undefined) {//geri_say!="undefined"
        console.log("tanımlanmamış")
        clearInterval(geri_say)
    }

    var a=0
    var geri_say = setInterval(function() {

        if (a==30) {
            abone_sayisi = 0
            $(".tren-sayisi").html(abone_sayisi)
            clearInterval(geri_say)
        }

        console.log(a)
        a++

        console.log("geri_say_temizle")
    },1000)
    }
```

Comment: probably because of the var in front of `var geri_say = ....`

Comment: remove **var** from **var geri_say** and declare it as global var

Comment: @epascarello I tried. thanks but it saying: Uncaught ReferenceError: geri_say is not defined.

Comment: So defined it outside the method

Comment: @epascarello excuse me, can you show me from jsfidde?

Comment: `var geri_say; function foo() { if (geri_say) { window.clearTimeout(geri_say); } geri_say = window.setTimeout(function(){},1000);  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of hoisting the `var geri_say` is moved to the top of the method and everytime you call the method, it overrides the variable so you can not reset it. So your code looks like this to the js engine:

```
function foo() {
  var geri_say;
  if (geri_say) {
    window.clearTimeout(geri_say); 
  }
  geri_say = window.setTimeout(function(){},1000);
}
```

So you can define it outside so it is not overwritten each time.

```
var geri_say;
function foo() {
  if (geri_say) {
    window.clearTimeout(geri_say); 
  }
  geri_say = window.setTimeout(function(){},1000);
}
```